# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE date format from csv

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile

I have been trying to pull a file into a table and the only issue I'm having is importing the dates (currently in `'MM/DD/YY'` format). No matter what I try they end up looking like `'0008-12-14'`. That date is `8/12/14` in the .csv file. I tried

```
SET ShipDate = STR_TO_DATE(@ShipDate,'%Y%m%d')
```

but then it imported them as `NULL`. The table field is set as `DATE`. Here's the code:

```
$query = <<<eof
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv'
     INTO TABLE HS_import
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
     IGNORE 1 LINES
    (AmountPaid,
ShipDate)
SET ShipDate = STR_TO_DATE(@ShipDate,'%Y%m%d')
eof;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yor format for the STR_TO_DATE is wrong. It should specify the INPUT format not the OUTPUT format:

```
SET ShipDate = STR_TO_DATE(@ShipDate,'%d%m%y')
```

So the whole thing should look like

```
  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv'
  INTO TABLE HS_import
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES
  (AmountPaid, @ShipDate)
  SET ShipDate = STR_TO_DATE(@ShipDate,'%d%m%y')
```